# The problem is that all values connected to Inspector become empty when called up dynamically by Prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity 2021.2.5f1 version is in use, and Prefab dynamic loading worked well until a few minutes ago, but it was forced to end after Unity error, and after loading Prefab, all the values connected to Inspector will be empty.

So if you check Prefab, it seems that the connected values are normally connected, and only when they are dynamically called in.

What should I do? Help me :-(
(Translated with a translator, so the English sentence may not be accurate.

Comment: Values are released just by dragging and dropping the prepap to the hierarchy without executing the unitity.

Answer (score 0):

It has been resolved with unit update and import all.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).